# How to add textfields dynamically and add information in to database?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form that I want to keep adding textfields to and then add the information to an entity in my database. I have the model configured yet can't think of the best approach to keep adding textfields and getting django to read them as the form will have other fields in it. So basically i have a form that has some fields and then once details are entered in to one of the fields it displays another. I am now stuck on how to pass the information to my application should i pass an array of numbers which is the length of the fields that have been used, then iterate through the array obtaining the information from the fields or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of text fields is arbitrary, you could add a new textfield via JavaScript when the last one is filled out and submit the value of the textfield via ajax. You might want to check out the JavaScript library, [jquery](http://www.jquery.com).

If you could add more specifics to the question I could be of more help.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention the number of additional fields could be infinite.

Comment: Ok. You would definitely want to add them via JavaScript then.  Give them all unique names like field_1 field_2 or whatever and when the user is done filling out the page and they submit it you can loop through field_1 through field_n and save the values.  Just check request for field_x until you don't get anything else to know how many there were.

Comment: OK thats the approach i was thinking. Will implement it now.